# Drupal 6: Feeds mapping node taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds

I using feeds module for import data from xml to node.

I have XML:

```
<root> 
<item>
<title>Example 1</title> <!-- map to node title-->
<body>Body of example 1</body> <!-- map to node title-->
<term_name>My_term</term_name>
<term_tid>15</term_tid>
</item>
</root>
```

```
SELECT tid, vid, name FROM term_data;
tid vid name
15  19  My_term
```

If I map `<term_name>` to my node taxonomy term (and term name exist) its working. 
But If i map `<term_tid>` to my node taxonomy term (and term tid exist) it's **NOT** working. Why?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve for category_tid:

```
function my_module_feeds_after_parse(FeedsImporter $importer, FeedsSource $source) {
if ($source != null && $source->id == 'import_my_module') {  
  $vid = 19 //id of vocabulary
    foreach ($source->batch->items as & $item) {
      if (($category = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT tid, vid, name, description FROM {term_data} WHERE tid= %d AND vid = %d", $item['<term_tid>'], $vid))) !== FALSE) {
        $item['<term_tid>'] = new FeedsTermElement($category);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before importing nodes from a site that contains taxonomy terms , try first to import all taxonomy terms ( you can use [taxonomy manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) ).

Feeds will add a term with a new tid if It not exist , not the same as tid of the site from where you export

Comment: All taxonomy term that i need exists. And I dont add new term by feeds (if doens't exist). I what map taxonomy term by nid